# Proving a ring in which $r^n=r$ for all $r$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity such that there is a positive integer $n\geq 2$ for which $r^n=r$ for all $r\in R$. Prove $R$ is commutative.

I had proven before that If $n=2$ it is commutative as follows:

$r+s=(r+s)^2=r^2+rs+sr+r^2=r+rs+sr+s\implies 0=rs+sr\implies sr=-rs$

On the other hand $-r=(-1)r=(-1)^2r=r$.

So $sr=-rs=rs$ as desired.

I seem to be stumped even with $n=3$.

Comment: Playing around with $n = 3$ and assuming that $r$ and $s$ commute, I seem to be getting that $r = -s$. I'm not sure if you get something similar for all $n$, but it seems like forcing $r^n = n$ for all $r \in R$ causes you to have very unusual rings where each element is the negative of every other element. There should probably be some caveat that we must have $s \neq 0 \neq r$, but I wasn't paying much attention to that.

Comment: @pjs36 I think you've probably made a mistake. If $n$ is prime, the stated property certainly holds for the prime field $\mathbb F_n$, for example. I think the solution could involve number theory as one can show that the characteristic of $R$ divides $k^n-k$ for each integer $k\ge1$. My number theory isn't strong enough to go further, however.

Comment: @Jason Ah, making mistakes, that sounds like me.

Comment: This question has been asked here in various forms, though in full generality I think this is a bit difficult for a homework problem. Perhaps you'll find this link helpful: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ggim/W14-110BH.pdf

Comment: thanks alex. that is really helpful

Comment: See the answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360958/prove-that-r-is-a-commutative-ring-if-x3-x/360968#360968 . I have no the book of Herestein. However, in this special case might exist a simple proof. Please, ask your professor to show the solution of this homework, and share the ideas with us.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/831124/15416, which also doesn't have an answer, but more links.

Comment: A MO discussion at which you may want to take a look: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29590/a-condition-that-implies-commutativity

Comment: Here is one more link, namely Herstein has a paper entitled "An elementary proof of a theorem of Jacobson", where he proves it on 4 pages: 
https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.dmj/1077465581

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The proof is found in the literature but is perhaps too long for an answer here on math.SE. We have long suffered from a lack of a canonical answer for this question, so this is an attempt at an approximation to one.*

---

Even more is true:

> If for each $x$ there exists an integer $n(x)>1$ such that $x^{n(x)}-x$ is in the center of $R$, then $R$ is commutative.

There are a few proofs in the literature, ones which are probably too long for a post here.

You should consult your local library to obtain a copy of one of these (probably preferring the newest one you can get):

> N. Jacobson, ["Structure theory for algebraic algebras of bounded degree"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969205), *Ann. of Math.* 46 (1945), 695–707.
>
> Herstein, I. N. ["An elementary proof of a theorem of Jacobson"](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-54-02105-5), *Duke Mathematical Journal* 21.1 (1954): 45-48.
>
> Rogers, Kenneth. ["An elementary proof of a theorem of Jacobson"](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02993626), *Abhandlungen aus dem Mathematischen Seminar der Universität Hamburg*. Vol. 35. No. 3. Springer Berlin/Heidelberg, 1971.

A proof of an even more general nature is also discussed as Theorem 3.2.3 in:

> Herstein, Israel Nathan. Noncommutative rings. Vol. 15. American Mathematical Soc., 1994.

There are also useful related questions on this site:

1. [$x^n = x$ implies commutativity, a universal algebraic proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2773974/29335)

Comment: The easiest proof appears in "Elementary proofs of a theorem of Wedderburn and a theorem of Jacobson" by Takasi Nagahara, Hisao Tominaga. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02993501

Answer (score 2):

The most elementary proofs of Jacobson's Theorem (with a fixed exponent $n$) were given by Wamsley, Dolan and Nagahara-Tominaga:

- J. W. Wamsley, *On a condition for commutativity of rings*, J. Lond. Math. Soc. 2.2 (1971), 331-332.
- S. W. Dolan, *A proof of Jacobson's Theorem*, Canad. Math. Bull. 19.1 (1976), 59-61.
- T. Nagahara, H. Tominaga. *Elementary proofs of a theorem of Wedderburn and a theorem of Jacobson*, Abh. Math. Semin. Univ. Hambg. 41 (1974), 72-74.

In contrast to other proofs, they do not use the axiom of choice. Unfortunately, they are still not constructive, in particular not equational.

I have recently found a method how to find an equational proof for every $n$: [Equational proofs of Jacobson's Theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.05301). The rough idea is to prove the reduction to prime characteristic and then to $n=p^k$ in a constructive way. Then, the (more or less equivalent) proofs by Dolan and Nagahara-Tominaga, which reduce the Theorem to Wedderburn's Theorem, can be made constructive as well. The paper discusses several examples. For example, every ring with $x^{2023}=x$ is commutative by an equational proof. This is just an example of infinitely many examples.