# $x^3 = x$ for all $x \in R$, where $R$ is a ring. Prove that $6x = 0$ for all $x \in R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am very confused about this problem. Because, clearly 6x = 0  only has one solution, 0. But I can make

> $x^3 = x$
>
> $x^3 -x=0$   *(Adding additive inverse of x to both sides)*
>
> $x(x^2-1)=0$ *(Distributive property of the ring)*
>
> $x(x+1)(x-1) = 0$ *(Distributive property of the ring again)*

which gives $x=0,1,-1$ as solutions. 
Not also I don't really know how to prove this problem, it confuses me how this is possible? Is it because the ring could not be an integral domain?

Comment: "6x = 0 only has one solution, 0" Not true in a ring!

Comment: Note that the problem states *for all* $x\in R$. Note also that your last conclusion does in fact assume $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: $R$ doesn't have to be an integral domain.

Comment: For instance, in $\mathbb{Z}/(6)$, every $x$ is a solution to $6x=0$.

Comment: If $1\in R$, since $2^3=2$, that is, $6=0$, which implies that $6x=0$ for all $x\in R$.

Comment: The information you want was already available on several solutions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67148/29335), but I see it seems you have several questions about this line of thought that might not be answered there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have $$(x+x)^3=x+x$$ so $$8x^3=2x$$ and thus $$8x=2x$$ and $$6x=0$$

Answer (score 4):

> **Lemma:** If $R$ is a ring and $a\cdot x=0$ for all $x\in R$, then $a=0$.

*Proof:* Take $x=1$. $\square$

> **Corollary:** Let $R$ be a ring and $a \in R$. Then $a=0$ if and only if $a\cdot x=0$ for all $x\in R$.

By the corollary, it suffices to show that $6=0$ in $R$.
To that end, notice that by hypothesis $2^3=2$ in $R$.

Comment: It is not given that 6 ∈ R. So it will be wrong to do so directly.

Comment: $6x$ doesn't make sense in that context. Adding to that, $6$ means only $1+1+1+1+1+1$, which is always some element of a ring $R$.

Comment: 6x is defined as x+x+x+x+x+x .

Comment: Yes, precisely, so $6$ always belongs to $R$.

Comment: @ShreedharBhat $6$ is defined as $1+1+1+1+1+1$.  (I'm assuming our ring is unital.)

Comment: Yes it does: add $x$ to itself six times. Also, your proof doesn't work if the ring is not assumed to have a unity. I think the simpler upvoted proof above is essentially the same idea without overextending the assumptions.

Comment: @Vik78 ? Rings have an element $1$ by definition (multiplicative identitiy). I don't know how simpler algebraic manipulations are. I think this answer shows the essence of the question (that $6=0$ in $R$).

Comment: Certainly not by everyone's definition. Ever heard of the term "unital ring?"

Comment: @Fimpellizieri In my textbook, the ring doesn't need to have multiplicative identity, 1.

Answer (score 3):

$(x\pm1)^3=x^3\pm3x^2+3x\pm1$ so using $x^3=x$:

$x\pm1=x\pm3x^2+3x\pm1$ so

$\pm3x^2+3x=0$

Adding for both + and -:

$6x=0$

Answer (score 2):

$(x+1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1=x+1=x+3x^2+3x+1$implies that $3x^2+3x=0$. $3(x^2+x)=0$.

$3((x+1)^2+x+1)=3(x^2+2x+1+x+1)=3(x^2+x)+6x+6=0$.

$(1+1)^3=1+1$, $8=2$ implies $6=0$, so $6x+6=6x=0$.