# $x^n=x$ implies commutativity in rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm looking for a proof and/or a hint for this. I just got finished for $n=2$, but got stuck proving it for general $n$, apparently some background knowledge is required that's not present in the book.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67148/if-a3-a-for-all-a-in-a-ring-r-then-r-is-commutative

Comment: Thanks, I already saw that. I'm looking for the general case of n>=2 though. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Read the whole page....

Comment: @InsertNameHere One of the solution at that link *did* answer the general question, if you would have read down to it. The one I linked to happens to be a very similar answer by the same user. Hopefully with this link, it will be harder to miss the general solution provided.