# If $a^{3}=a$ for all $a\in R$, show that the ring $R$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, abelian-groups

> If $a^{3}=a$ for all $a\in R$, show that the ring $R$ is commutative.

I tried to follow [Ehsan M. Kermani](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/360980)'s answer, but I thought wouldn't the following be sufficient?

Let $a,b\in R$. Then $a^{3}=a$ and $b^{3}=b$. Then $ab=a^{3}b^{3}=(ba)^{3}=ba$.

Comment: How did you go from $a^3 b^3$ to $(ba)^3$? I'm pretty sure that step is non-trivial.

Comment: Based on link. Because for any $a$, $a^2\in Z(R)$ we got that $ab=(ab)^3=ababab=a(ba)^2b=(ba)^2ab=baba^2b=ba^3b^2=bab^2=b^3a=ba$.

Comment: Why does $a(ba)^2b = (ba)^2ab$?

Comment: By definition $Z(R)=\{a\in R |\forall_{b\in R} ab=ba\}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $a^3 =a$ for all $a$ in a ring $R$, then $R$ is commutative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67148/if-a3-a-for-all-a-in-a-ring-r-then-r-is-commutative)