# Show that the ring is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> $$R\textrm{ is a ring(multiplicative identity not assumed) such that }x^{3}=x \: \: \forall x\in R.\\
> \textrm{Prove that }R\textrm{ is a commutative ring }.$$

---

I have been able to show that $6x=0$ for all $x$ in $R$. Can I get some hints on how to proceed?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67148/if-a3-a-for-all-a-in-a-ring-r-then-r-is-commutative

Comment: thanks. will check it out